# ¿Por qué no puedo usar Facades dentro de un archivo custom helpers.php en Laravel 11?

Tags: php, laravel

**CONTEXTO.** Laravel 11.

**PROBLEMA.**

He creado un archivo */config/constantes.php* para ubicar ahí algunas constantes que quiero que estén disponibles globalmente, y este es su contenido:

```
<?php
    return [
        'mime_types' => [
            'images' => [
                'image/apng',
                'image/avif ',
                'image/gif',
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/svg+xml',
                'image/webp',
            ],
        ]
    ];
```

Tengo este controlador */app/Http/Controllers/MediaController.php*, con el siguiente contenido:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
class MediaController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request): View
    {
        $mimes = Config::get('constantes.mime_types.images');
        print_r($mimes);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Cuando accedo al método index() de ese controlador se imprime en pantalla perfectamente el contenido del key *images* del archivo constantes.php.

He creado otro archivo **/app/Helpers/helpers.php** según estas [instrucciones](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-11-create-custom-helper-functions-exampleexample.html#google_vignette), donde tengo mis funciones personalizadas. Dentro de helpers.php quiero recuperar también el contenido del key *images* dentro de constantes.php, y lo hago así:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
$mimes = Config::get('constants.mime_types.images');
$mimes = config('constantes.mime_types.images');
```

Pero saltan estos errores:

1. A facade root has not been set
2. Class "config" does not exist in...

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Qué me falta por hacer? Por favor, ¡ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Pasos a seguir para solucionar mi problema:

1. Crear /app/Helpers/helpers.php (en teoría debería poderse crear el archivo en cualquier ruta). Dentro de este archivo van nuestras funciones y nada más.
2. Editamos /composer.json y agregamos `"files": ["app/Helpers/helpers.php" ]` dentro de la sección **autoload**.
3. Ecutamos el comando `composer dump-autoload`. Con esto ya están disponibles nuestros helpers globalmente.
4. Ahora creamos /config/constantes.php con las constantes que queramos (ver mi ejemplo en mi pregunta hasta arriba en este post)
5. Tal como quedó asentado en mi pregunta de este post, yo estaba intentando recuperar información de constantes.php así desde mi helpers.php: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config; $mimes = Config::get('constantes.mime_types.images');` pero me saltaban los problemas que indiqué antes.
6. Me di por rendido al no poder recuperar mis constantes así que seguí trabajando sin usar el facade Config, pero me animé a usar otro facade: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; $mimeType = File::mimeType($rutaAlArchivo);` y extrañamente sí funcionó, ¿por qué éste sí y el otro no? No lo sé. Pero al ver que sí funcionó este segundo facade me animé a intentar nuevamente usar el facade **Config** y de nuevo me sorprendí al ver que ahora sí funcionó. Antes de hacer esto había borrado todas las cachés de Laravel, había borrado caché del navegador, reiniciado computadora, y nada ayudó. Lo único que percibí es que después de usar un 2do facade comenzó a funcionar el 1er facade.

Sobre la respuesta que posteó **@williamrb** casi estoy seguro que la obtuvo de alguna IA, porque antes de llegar aquí yo mismo usé a Gemini y ChatGPT y me dieron respuestas muy parecidas a las de williamrb, pero no funcionaron porque hablaban como si yo hubiera pedido ayuda para una versión vieja de Laravel. Esas respuestas no funcionan más en Laravel 11.

Answer (score -1):

El problema que estás enfrentando se debe a que Laravel no ha sido capaz de localizar la clase config en tu aplicación. Esto puede ocurrir por varias razones, como un problema con el registro de servicios en el contenedor de Laravel o un problema con la configuración del alias para la clase config.

Puedes solucionar este problema siguiendo estos pasos:

1. Comprueba que el alias para la clase `config` esté correctamente configurado en el archivo `config/app.php`. En la sección `aliases`, asegúrate de que la clase `config` esté registrada con el alias `config`.
2. Comprueba que el servicio `config` esté registrado en el contenedor de **Laravel**. Puedes hacer esto agregando el siguiente código al método `register` de tu proveedor de servicios:

   ```
   $this->app->singleton('config', function ($app) {
       return new Config($app);
   });
   ```

En este ejemplo, se crea un nuevo objeto `Config` y se registra como servicio en el contenedor de **Laravel**.

3. Comprueba que el archivo `config/sanctum.php` esté presente y que contenga la clase **Sanctum** con el método `currentApplicationUrlWithPort()`. Este método es utilizado por **Laravel** para obtener la **URL** actual del aplicativo con el puerto correcto.
4. Comprueba que el método `make` de la clase `Illuminate\Foundation\Application` esté configurado para crear instancias de clases que no están registradas en el contenedor de **Laravel**. Puedes hacer esto agregando el siguiente código al método `make`:

   ```
   public function make($abstract = 'config', $parameters = [])
   {
       if ($abstract === 'config') {
           return new Config($this);
       }

       // Rest of the code...
   }
   ```

En este ejemplo, se crea una nueva instancia de la clase `Config` cuando se solicita el servicio `config` a través del método `make`.

5. Comprueba que el archivo `bootstrap/cache/config.php` esté presente y que contenga las clases y métodos necesarios para la configuración de **Laravel**. Si este archivo no existe o está incompleto, puedes generarlo ejecutando el comando `php artisan config:cache`.

Si sigues teniendo problemas, puedes probar a eliminar el archivo `bootstrap/cache/config.php` y ejecutar el comando `php artisan config:cache` para regenerarlo.

De no funcionarte haciéndolo de la manera que te he puesto arriba, puedes ver las referencias de los `facades` para verificar si estás referenciando a la clase correcta.

Aquí te dejo la tabla de la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/facades#facade-class-reference) de algunos facades en **Laravel 11** donde encontrarás los `facades` con sus clases y la clave de vinculación del contenedor de servicios (`Service Container Binding`):

| Facade | Class | Service Container Binding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| App | Illuminate\Foundation\Application | app |
| Artisan | Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel | artisan |
| Cache | Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager | cache |
| Cache (Instance) | Illuminate\Cache\Repository | cache.store |
| Config | Illuminate\Config\Repository | config |
| DB | Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager | db |
| DB (Instance) | Illuminate\Database\Connection | db.connection |
| URL | Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator | url |

Espero que estos pasos te ayuden a resolver el problema y que puedas utilizar las facades dentro de tu archivo `helpers.php` sin problemas.

Comment: Recuerda evitar usar inteligencia artificial para crear respuestas en el sitio, ya que tu cuenta puede ser suspendida,saludos.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé, en Laravel 11 no existe la sección "aliases" en app.php, y tampoco existe el archivo bootstrap/cache/config.php. Antes de llegar a postear mi problema aquí en StackOverflow probé con ChatGPT y Gemini, y me dieron respuestas muy parecidas a la que diste, @williamrb, pero no solucionaron mi problema porque ya no aplican a Laravel 11. Tu respuesta y las de las IA que mencioné, funcionan bien en versiones viejas de Laravel, como Laravel 8.